# Приоритеты вычислений в javascript

Tags: javascript

Учу javascript - Столкнулся с вопросом... Почему в выражении (5||1&&(x=1)); alert(x);
переменной x не присваивается значение? Ведь приоритет у &&(И) выше чем у ||(ИЛИ), (И)возвращает в данном случаи (x=1),тем самым запуская выражение и присваивая x = 1.
Но alert() возвращает underfined!

Comment: скинь весь код

Comment: правая часть выражения не выполняется т.к. левая - true, соответственно в этом нет необходимости.

PS: пожалуйста, старайтесь не писать присваивание в условиях.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

var x;

(5||1&&(x=1));
alert(x);


</script>

Comment: @AlexWinHope почему не надо писать операцию присваивания в условиях? Си (а соответственно и его наследники) поощряет побочные эффекты

Comment: &&(И)возвращает первое false, или последнее true, - в нашем случаи оно выполняется!
P.S.Так &&(И) это логическое умножение 1(true) будет только в том случаи если все значения будут 1(true)! потому оператор проверяет до конца - все аргументы, если встречается 0(false), то возвращается первый false, потому что дальнейшая проверка нет смысла
 1 * 0 * 1*  1 * 1 = 0!

Comment: @klondike а какой смысл выполнять &&, если первый операнд || уже истина (5)? А приоритет && выше приоритета ||.

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript операторы && и || возвращают не булево значение, а один из операндов подбробнее [тут](http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators).

Пример:

```
var x = 1, y = 2;
console.log(x || y); // 1
console.log(x && y); // 2
```

P.S. Эти операторы равноправые и выполняются слева направо, возвращая первое не false значение.

Comment: это понятно... и по идеи x должен вывести 1! Но выводит underfined!

Comment: Да не должен быть один, первое операнд у вас "5", а это "true". Выражение испольняется слева направо, до первого "true", в вашем случае, это "5", извините за тавтологию.

Comment: 5 - это результат которое вернет выражения (5||1&&(x=1), но при проверки &&(И) также дойдет до (x=1) тем самым запустив присвоение, а в alert(x)мы выводим x, а не выражение alert(5||1&&(x=1)).
что бы понять суть вопроса просто запустите у себя код:

<script type="text/javascript">
var x;
(5||1&&(x=1)); alert(x);
</script>

Comment: Дружище, это JS, всё, дальше "5" он не пойдет и вернет его, не будет никого &&, он уже получил свой "true". http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators — прочтите это.

Comment: Только для вас — http://www.rubaxa.org/screenshot/035925ff98d8d2f416b121f06961.png
var x; // undefined
console.log(   (5 || 1 && (x = 1))    ); // 5
alert(x); // undefined

Comment: Я прочитал это - http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators.
Если вы мне говорите за "Сокращенные вычисления":

false && что угодно становится false.
true || что угодно становится true.

Да я согласен это действительно так, но в вашем примере рассматриваются не комбинированные выражения, только

1(true)||0(false) или 
0(false)&&1(true), 

а не комбинированное выражение:

значение1||значение2&&значение3 

здесь выражение будет считаться, с тем же сокращением, если оно возможно, но с учетом ПРИОРИТЕТОВ операторов: сначала&&, а потом ||.

Comment: Нет, вы реально отказыватесь воспринимать то, что я говорю, да фиг со мной, сам js вам говорит, что у него нет никаких приоритетов и он тупо считывает славо направо, но вы отказывайтесь верить своим глазам. Вот вам ещё один пример — http://jsfiddle.net/8KEPn/

Comment: @klondike эквивалент

      if (5) then true;
      else if (1) then 
        if(x=1) then true;
        else false;
     else false;